# discord.py guild.members property returns only online members

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I don't think this is the expected behaviour (why would [`voice_channel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.VoiceChannel.members) exist otherwise?).

My code (nothing special):

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.guild = self.bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)

        for m in self.guild.members:
            print(m.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions, you have to define it to get channels, members and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).

Comment: totally missed this update, thanks! just a thing, you missed a typo in `discord.Intents.all()` ;)